# How to create an Excel Hierarchy

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create an Excel hierarchy (very similar to this question)
[Creating an excel hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735976/creating-an-excel-hierarchy)

but the structure of my Excel file is quite different.
Please see the layout of my file by comparison:

[image: Excel file structure]

I would like to have this as an expandable hierarchy in a pivot table or through VBA (whatever is easier) like the below:

[image]

Whilst the image above shows Tier, my desired output would use the Level value. This is where the structure mentioned above means it isn't as easy as following the steps from the linked question.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefan.

Comment: Please include the expected result for the example you show.

Comment: If you are not able to explain exactly what you need, was it so difficult to show us a picture of YOUR DESIRED OUTPUT? The picture you show us is copied from the linked question, as it was there, without any connection to your question. The question, as it is expressed, is clear only in your head. If you really need help, you must make at least the effort to make us understand what you want...

Comment: use a pivot table and choose the "outline form" [layout option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/design-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-a9600265-95bf-4900-868e-641133c05a80). Remove the [subtotals](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-subtotals-from-a-pivottable-b02bc742-988a-4b64-a186-6a865a585a8e)

Comment: Hi all, I've modified the question to explain that I would require the Level value to be used as the equivalent to Tier (but the structure of my excel file is fundamentally different to that of the linked question).

Comment: But you should be able to create manually an example of the output you need - with your data. Maybe by creating this you already get an idea of how to migrate your original data set. ...

Comment: Do you really think you clarified the question? Why is it so difficult to manually build a range with the desired result and make a picture from it, if not something editable to be used on testing, if somebody will like to try a solution? Do you mean "Part Description Level" when say "Level"? If so, why you fill the need to save words? If not, what do you want meaning? How many columns should your desired hierarchy should contain? Do you want us guessing what is to be done? If your structure if "fundamentally different", should the output be the same? How can it be so?

Comment: @StefanHanotin I can only repeat my first request: Please [edit] your question and show a screenshot of your desired output. From the data you show and the explanation we are not able to see how your result should look like. VBA cannot do any magic.

Comment: Hi all, I've updated the question with a screenshot of the desired output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will only need those columns:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' read data into array
    Dim PartNumber() As Variant
    PartNumber = ws.Range("D2", "D" & LastRow).Value

    Dim PartDescription() As Variant
    PartDescription = ws.Range("E2", "E" & LastRow).Value

    Dim PartLevel() As Variant
    PartLevel = ws.Range("F2", "F" & LastRow).Value

    Dim PartParent() As Variant
    PartParent = ws.Range("G2", "G" & LastRow).Value
    
    ' creat a tree
    Dim RootTree As Object
    Set RootTree = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' fill tree with data
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(PartNumber, 1) To UBound(PartNumber, 1)
        If PartLevel(iRow, 1) = 0 Then
            ' create root
            ' ------------
            RootTree.Add PartNumber(iRow, 1), CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Else
            ' create all children
            ' --------------------
            Dim BacktraceLevel As Long
            BacktraceLevel = PartLevel(iRow, 1)
            ReDim Backtrace(1 To BacktraceLevel)
            
            Backtrace(BacktraceLevel) = PartParent(iRow, 1)
            BacktraceLevel = BacktraceLevel - 1
            
            ' backtrace from current child to root
            Do While BacktraceLevel > 0
                DoEvents
                Dim FoundAt As Double
                FoundAt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Backtrace(BacktraceLevel + 1), PartNumber, 0)
                If PartLevel(FoundAt, 1) <> 0 Then
                    Backtrace(BacktraceLevel) = PartParent(FoundAt, 1)
                End If
                BacktraceLevel = BacktraceLevel - 1
            Loop
            
            ' climb tree until child can be added
            Dim Parent As Object
            Set Parent = RootTree
            Dim b As Long
            For b = 1 To UBound(Backtrace)
                Set Parent = Parent(Backtrace(b))
            Next b
            
            ' add current child
            Parent.Add PartNumber(iRow, 1), CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    ' output tree
    OutputTree RootTree, Worksheets("output").Range("A1"), PartNumber, PartDescription
End Sub

Private Sub OutputTree(ByVal Tree As Object, ByVal StartOutput As Range, ByVal PartNumber As Variant, ByVal PartDescription As Variant, Optional ByVal Level As Long = 0)
    Static iRow As Long
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In Tree.Keys
        StartOutput.Offset(RowOffset:=iRow, ColumnOffset:=Level).Value = PartDescription(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Key, PartNumber, 0), 1)
        iRow = iRow + 1
        If VarType(Tree(Key)) = 9 Then
            OutputTree Tree(Key), StartOutput, PartNumber, PartDescription, Level + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And it will output

[image]